# Grib2 Libraries For .Net

Tags: .net, library, weather, grib-2

Are there any good libraries for accessing [GRIB2](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/grib2/grib2_doc.shtml) data in .Net?  Specifically, I want to be able to quickly pull subsets of weather data from a grib2 file based on time and location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fwtools.maptools.org/

With FWTools there are .NET wrappers for the GDAL, which can read .GRB (GRIB2) files.

Comment: Wonderful.  I'll give it a shot tonight, but from what I read I think it may work.  If so, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

[GribApi.NET](https://github.com/0x1mason/GribApi.NET) is now freely available. It supports reading and writing GRIB 1 and 2 files.

Disclosure: I am the author of the C# wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

GribCS gives fine grained access to grib files. Using GDAL you might be loosing some interesting information.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gribcs/files/

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with .NET, but the standard c library for accessing grib2 files is [g2clib](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/grib2/download/). You could call the functions of that dll. I think it is better than using gdal, because you are more likely to cover every aspect of the grib2 definition.

Comment: Haven't seen that one before.  I'll give it a look.  Thanks!